# Monotonicity in ratio of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Is $${\sum\limits_{i=0}^n x^i \over\sum\limits_{i=0}^n p^ix^i}$$ increasing in $x\in(0,1)$ for $p\in(0,1)$?

It seems that this problem is equivalent to proving the following inequality: $$(\sum_{i=0}^n x^i)(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n p^ix^i)>(n+1)x^n(\sum_{i=0}^n p^i).$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Assume $p,x\in(0,1)$ and let: 
$$ f(x)=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n x^i}{\sum_{i=0}^n (px)^i},\quad g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}x^i.\tag{1}$$
We have:
$$ f(x+h)-f(x) = \frac{g(x+h)g(px)-g(x)g(px+ph)}{g(px)g(px+ph)}\tag{2}$$
hence it is enough to prove that:
$$\left(g(x+h)-g(x)\right)g(px)-g(x)\left(g(px+ph)-g(px)\right)\geq 0 \tag{3}$$ 
or:
$$ g'(x) g(px) \leq p\cdot g(x)g'(px)\tag{4} $$
that is equivalent to:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\log(g(x)) \leq \frac{d}{dx}\log(g(px)) \tag{5} $$
that is not difficult to check.

That also follows from a useful lemma: if $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n$ and $g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}b_n x^n$ are two analytic functions over $(0,1)$, $a_n,b_n>0$ and $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is an increasing function with respect to $n$, then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is an increasing function with respect to $x$.